# How to store list in Django model field while using SQLite

Tags: arrays, json, django, list, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm stuck with the issue that I need to insert the list [ ] in the model field while using SQLite,

Group_Model.py:

```
class ClassificationGroup(models.Model):
   vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   classification_id = models. [what do i take here to make it capable to store list of ids that will be related to the classification table.]
```

Classification_Model.py

```
class Classification(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   description = models. CharField(max_length=1000)
   domain_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

i just want to store the list of classification in the one field of the Classification Group Mentioned above, Please help me out in this.

Comment: And why not [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)?

Comment: Because one classification Group contains many classifications it's One to Many Relationship

Comment: i used this relation [Many to Many] it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a method to your class to convert it automatically.

```
import json


class ClassificationGroup(models.Model):
    #...
    classification_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def set_classification_id (self, lst):
        self.classification_id = json.dumps(lst)

    def get_classification_id (self):
        return json.loads(self.classification_id)
```

your view:

```
obj = ClassificationGroup.objects.create(name="name",**data)
obj.set_classification_id([1,2,3])
obj.save()
#there are several examples of using this method
```

your HTML:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
 {{ obj.name }}
 {{ obj.get_classification_id }}
{% endfor %}
```